# Can I make Dynamo DB tables unavailable based on usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS, and now I'd like to use a DynamoDB table in the **on-demand mode** for my hobby project.

Is it possible to stop the table after a million read/write request units were made? I just want to make sure that I won't have to pay for more than $1.25 for write requests and $0.25 for read requests per month, which is documented [on this page](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/). (I use us-east, Ohio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't stop the table, but you can set an alarm in CloudWatch to trigger when the consumed capacity reaches 1M. Make sure that your alarm sums over an entire period of time, not per second.

If you are new to DynamoDB then I strongly advise you to use DynamoDB Local or use provisioned mode where you can get 25WCU/RCU for free per region as part of the free tier. That would allow you to write more than 2M items per day for free.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, by choosing the provisioned mode, DynamoDB will create CloudWatch alarms (`ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits` & `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits`). Consequently, when my usage is below the provisioned capacity, the alarms will be triggered, and triggering the alarms costs fees. Unless your DB tables get 1M+ read/write requests, the on-demand mode is more economical, isn't it?

Comment: No, remove the autoscaling and you won't have to deal with alarms. As I mentioned, 25RCU and 25WCU are free, so set your table to that limit with no scaling. You'll have as much capacity as you need and won't pay for alarms.

Comment: OK... but after I disabled auto-scaling and set 25WCU/RCU for a table that I use, I can see "Estimated cost $17.70 / month" on the Edit read/write capacity page (For this time, the region is Frankfurt, eu-central-1). I don't know if it's really free

Comment: PS: You answered my original question, so I marked it as the accepted answer. Again, thanks for your advice!

Comment: 25 capacity units are free for reads and writes per region, not per table. https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all&all-free-tier.q=Dynamodb&all-free-tier.q_operator=AND